# what could be causing my new starter not engage the flywheel?

Tags: starter

So my 84 ford f150 starter went out. I replaced it with a new one the next day. it started up strong no problem for a couple days the boom! the same problem. I can hear spinning from the starter which is brand new but no crank from the engine, what could be my problem?? its like something keeps causing my starter to fail.

Comment: Did the previous one have exactly the same symptoms (starter spinning, but pinion not engaging with the ring gear)?

Comment: You probably have a bad starter ring gear, which is part of the flywheel or torque converter.

Comment: worn teeth on the flywheel
poor earth connection